# Using a JOIN within a UNION ALL view creation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am creating a view merging two tables with some similar fields and some dissimilar fields.  I have this 95% working but there is one field from table A that matches up with a field from table B but only if you use that field from B as a join to pull a field from table C.  The only part of the code below that isn't working is the JOIN.  I could just put both of the fields in and do the logic to get `provider_id` from the `ehruser_id` in the model, but I feel like it should be doable in the SQL and I just don't have the knowledge to get that last bit working yet

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vunifiedschedule CASCADE;
CREATE VIEW vunifiedschedule AS
SELECT
    schedule_block.id as vid,
    schedule_block.reason as vblock_reason,
    NULL as vappointment_reason_id,
    schedule_block.when_ts as vwhen,
    schedule_block.deleted_ts as vdeleted_when,
    schedule_block.placeofservice_id as vlocation_id,
    schedule_block.duration as vduration,
    true as vappointment_book,
    schedule_block.note as vnote
FROM schedule_block
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id FROM provider) as vprovider_id ON provider.ehruser_id = schedule_block.ehruser_id
UNION ALL
SELECT
    appointment.id AS vid,
    NULL as vblock_reason,
    appointment.appointmentreason_id AS vappointment_reason_id,
    appointment.appt_when AS vwhen,
    appointment.deleted_when AS vdeleted_when,
    appointment.location_id AS vlocation_id,
    appointment.visit_length AS vduration,
    appointment.appointment_book as vappointment_book,
    appointment.note AS vnote,
    appointment.provider_id as vprovider_id
FROM appointment
```

The error I get is 
`ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "provider"
LINE 14: ...ELECT id FROM provider) as vprovider_id ON provider.e...`

Comment: The plain english version of what I'm trying to do is "Find the row in the `provider` table where the value in the `ehruser_id` column matches the value of the `ehruser_id` column in the current row of the `schedule_block` table.  Get the id from that row and use it as `vprovider_id`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear.  You have no `provider`.  I think you intend:

```
FROM schedule_block LEFT JOIN
     ( SELECT id FROM provider) vprovider_id
     ON vprovider.ehruser_id = schedule_block.ehruser_id
--------^
```

However the subquery is unnecessary:

```
FROM schedule_block LEFT JOIN
     provider
     ON provider.ehruser_id = schedule_block.ehruser_id
```

Comment: @mrben522 . . . You are not even selecting from `vprovider` in the select.  And if you were, you would only take the column that you want.  I really do not understand what your comment really means.  You get only the columns you reference in the outer `select`.

Comment: This solution was correct, I was missing the other half of the JOIN (adding the column to the select)

Answer (score 1):

1. 1st select stmt of view has 9 columns but 2nd select stmt has 10 columns. This view will error with message "Query block has incorrect number of result columns

Comment: The `JOIN` is the 10th column

Answer (score 0):

You selected 9 columns from the first table and 10 from the second, when using union you must have the same number of columns in both queries and the type columns selected must match.

Comment: The JOIN is the 10th column

Comment: The JOIN column must also appear in the select list.  Since it's not you are not actually selecting it. The JOIN is part of the FROM Clause not the SELECT.